# RactiveJS and JSX

Tags: reactjs, ractivejs

Is RactiveJS compatible with JSX?

I'm guessing some of the mark-up is not compatible. I like the thought of strong typing and being able to cleanly write the templates in JavaScript source. Maybe this is considered bad design?

Comment: Do you mean [JSX](http://jsx.github.io/), the language that compiles to JavaScript, or [JSX](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), the pre-processor for React.js? One is concerned with strong typing, the other is concerned with writing UI component markup in js source code.

Comment: To clarify, the JSX that pre-processes React.js, so that you can use templates inside js source code.

Comment: Read this blog post... http://blog.ractivejs.org/posts/whats-the-difference-between-react-and-ractive/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. React.js and Ractive.js have many similarities (for example, both work by constructing a lightweight virtual DOM in memory), but they have one very major difference - React completely rejects the idea of templates.

Which is to say that JSX *isn't a templating language*, it just looks like one! In React, if you have something like this...

```html
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

...it gets converted to something like this by the JSX pre-processor:

```js
React.DOM.h1(null, 'Hello world!');
```

In other words JSX describes functions, rather than templates. In Ractive, by contrast, Mustache templates are parsed into tree-like structures that can be transported as JSON.

Now, in the case of that example it doesn't really matter what process the original string goes through - it's still going to end up as an `<h1>` element in a browser somewhere. But it gets a lot harder when you start introducing arbitrary JavaScript which refers to `this.state` and `this.props` - things that can alter the fundamental structure of a component in React, but which have no meaning in Ractive.

Ractive might support templating languages other than Mustache in future, but JSX is unlikely to be one of them because they have such different approaches and design goals.

However there's a related issue here, which is being able to fully describe components in a single file. There's some [ongoing work](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/issues/299) happening there - the most likely scenario is that we'll be able to describe components in an .html file (since you can use JavaScript and CSS inside HTML) rather than writing the template into your .js file.

Comment: I've always thought the "JSX isnt a template" claim doesn't hold up. Almost all templating languages worthy of note do exactly the same thing, convert tags and so on into similarly structured underlying language.